# What does it mean - have hard it back?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does it mean?

> That's the guy who stole my account but **have hard it back**.

Here is the context:

> Question in Messenger on Facebook: **Who is this boy on photo?**
>   Answer: **That's the guy who stole my account but have hard it back.**

Comment: Note to OP - In the future, please remember: context belongs in the question, not in the comments below the question

Answer (score 1):

That sentence doesn't mean anything. It looks like a typo, and I'm not even sure what the intended meaning would have been. Perhaps "but I have it back" or "but [the guy] has handed it back"?

Comment: I'd suggest "but I have had it back". Hard to tell though